# is it ok to use try/catch instead of checking for duplicate when inserting in db with unique column?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, innodb

so i have a table which has a unique column

```
transactions : id , trace_code (unique) , amount , created_at
```

i have a robot which reads my transactions from bank api and insert them in my db every x minutes with cronjob ... so there's a lot of duplicate values on each execution

so i can check for duplicates before inserting data on that table 
but its much easier to just insert in a try/catch block  ... it means less code and fewer query

```
try {

 $tr = new Transaction();
 $tr->amount = 1000 ;
 $tr->trace_code = 123 ; 
 $tr->save();
}
catch(\Exception $e){

  echo " duplicate value";
}
```

so my question is there any downside to do insert this way when i know there would be a lot of duplicated values ?

Comment: This question is probably more on topic on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could just use `INSERT IGNORE` [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is the correct way. Otherwise An other request might insert a row after you check if it exists, but before you manage to do the insert. (In case 2 instances of your cron job happens to be running at the same time).

But please verify that the exception you get, is really from a unique index exception, and not something other which failed, so you don't end up ignoring other errors.

Comment: In other words, ideally you'd catch something less generic (ideally `\PDOException`) and verify the error code returned by MySQL.

Comment: It will catch all the exception from the base Exception which would be wrong. Better to set a unique index or use, firstOrNew etc

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in Eloquent's `firstOrNew` method. Itll create a new instance of the model without saving immediately if no matching record is found. You can then decide to save/update accordingly:

```
// $tr will be the first matching record or a new instance
$tr = Transaction::firstOrNew([
    'amount' => 1000,
    'trace_code' => 123
]);

// do stuff....
$tr->save();
```

Use [locks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#pessimistic-locking) to protect from other queries updating the rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a potential problem in the other answers -- the burning of ids.

Assuming your table contains

```
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
trace_code ... UNIQUE
```

then...  When you attempt to insert a duplicate row (because of `trace_code`) and it traps (or is `IGNOREd`), the `id` has already been bumped.

Take a look at `SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl` to see if that has happened.

At some point, `INT` will overflow; this will cause trouble.

The solution I like is to get rid of `id` and make `trace_code` be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Then `INSERT IGNORE` either insert or silently do nothing.  No extra checks, trapping, etc, are needed.  (Continue to do try..catch -- in case *something else* goes wrong.  "Catch" should be for exceptions, not the "norm".)

There are other solutions, but they are messier.

Comment: thanx , interesting i didnt know that about the id , although im going to keep it bcuz my framework ORM needs id to be in table .... but im going to test what you said